# How to filter alignment columns based on list of position in biopython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, biopython, sequence-alignment

Based on the biopython help page [here](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Align.MultipleSeqAlignment-class.html), I can filter the alignment columns based on first or last 10, I can even piece together subalignment using

```
align[:, :10] + align[:, -10:]
```

`align` being an MSA object, generated using

```
from Bio import AlignIO
align = AlignIO.read("Clustalw/opuntia.aln", "clustal")
```

But, is it possible to, say extract column based on list of position. For example,
if i have a following list:

```
a=[12, 52, 68,45]
```

Is there a way to extract just these columns from the alignment `align`.

An `R` package called `bio3d` comes in handy to filter alignment by providing list as input (by doing: `filtered_align = align[, a]`), but would be great if i can use this from python.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Biopython docs](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Align.MultipleSeqAlignment-class.html#__getitem__), you can get column x with

```
align[:, x]
```

So the following should do the job for you:

```
from Bio import AlignIO

align = AlignIO.read("Clustalw/opuntia.aln", "clustal")
indices = [12, 52, 68, 45]
columns_as_strings = []

for column in indices:
    columns_as_strings.append(align[:, column])
```

Comment: What if I don't want a list returned, but a MultipleAlignment object?